# Access violation when using double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function `func()` that takes a double pointer. If that points to zero, the function exits (first check). Now without the second check, I get an access violation trying to access the member of `mybar` (when I run the function a second time only). Why is that? If `mybar == NULL` shouldn't it exit at the first check?

```
func( Foo **bar )
{
    //First check
    if(bar== NULL)
    return;

    Foo *mybar = *bar;

    //Second check
    if(mybar == NULL)
        return;

    if(mybar->member != NULL)  //Access violation here if I dont have the 'second check'
    {
        //do stuff
    }    
    delete mybar;

    *bar = NULL;

}
```

Thats how I call it:

```
Foo *bar = NULL;
initialize(&bar); 
func(&bar);
func(&bar); //Second time I call it, I get the access violation
```

Comment: show how you call the function

Comment: @claptrap Thanks, I added the call. Actually it blows when I call it a second time. I want to proof it so I can actually call it a second time and it just returns without an access violation.

Comment: Show you *initialize()* function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bar` variable is never `NULL`, because it is not a dynamic variable. You probably mistook this definition:

```
Foo *bar = NULL;
```

Here `bar` is a non dynamically allocated variable, so `&bar` is always (in this scope) a valid address. It only *points* to `NULL` address.

Let's say you dynamically allocate some memory to `bar` in your `initialiase()` function, then your first call would look:

```
func(address_of_bar)
```

and inside this function, `*bar` points to dynamically allocated memory (a valid, non `NULL` address). Then you deallocate that memory through `delete mybar`, which in turn translates to `delete *bar`.

When you call `func()` for the second time, the call itself remains the same - `func(address_of_bar)`, as I have mentioned before, `&bar` is always non `NULL` here. But inside this function, `*bar == NULL`, because you have already deleted dynamically allocated memory when called `func()` for the first time. That's why your first check passes, but the second fails.

EDIT: to avoid such confusion I would suggest to use different names for variables and function parameters, especially when they are of different type (`Foo *bar` vs `Foo **bar`).

Comment: Thank you! i added the the first check `if(bar == NULL || *bar == NULL )`

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because you are not checking if your pointer is pointing to NULL or not.

first check `if(bar== NULL)` says that your pointer isn't NULL, **BUT** it can still points to a NULL value (it is just an address after all)
Second check `if(mybar == NULL)` does exactly the same. The pointer is not null(some address is assigned) but it can still points to NULL value. You are not checking that and you are trying to access field of object right away whitch is probably NULL.

Answer (score 0):

mybar does not have to be NULL to cause an access violation. It could point outside of the process address, protected memory or somewhere else invalid.

Most likely you forgot to initialise these pointers elsewhere in your code.